# iOS WindowsAzureMobileService framework - Predicate with like keyword

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, azure-mobile-services

How to apply predicate MSQuery with like keyword on WindowsAzureMobileService  framework.. ?

> When i tried with like keyword in predicate MSQuery, am getting
>   **ERROR: [-1400] - The predicate is not supported**

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Date >= '2016-05-27 00:00:00'  and  (Value like 'ABC%')"];
```

let me know how to use like keyword on MobileService framework in iOS

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` keyword is not supported currently. You can instead use: `value BEGINSWITH 'ABC'`

For querying for substrings, you can use `CONTAINS`.